# How to classification Hyperspectral data set with LibSVM and training SVM with .mat file?

Tags: classification, libsvm

I am trying to do classification Hyperspectral dataset using LibSVM.

I have two set of data:

1. one .mat file containing 145*145 pixel in 200 bands.
2. one .mat file containing 145*145 pixel for 16 classes label(value
   from 1 to 16).(background value is 0)

more information in this link: [Indain_pines_dataset](http://www.ehu.es/ccwintco/index.php?title=Hyperspectral_Remote_Sensing_Scenes)

My question is: How to sampling specific number or percent pixel of classes for training and testing LibSVM (training_label_vector and testing label vector) for 16 class.

My goal is multiclass classification of This data.

Please help..

Comment: Fragment revised and improved

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you the general idea :

First select your samples on the ground truth ( 16 classes image) :

Idx = cell (16,1) ;
Sample = zeros(no_samples) ;

for k = 1 : 16

[~,Idx{k}] = find(HSI == k-1) ;

[~,Sample(k)] = datasample(Idx{k},no_samples) ;

end

Idx is a cell with all the indices of the pixels of each class. The Kth column of Sample contains the members of Idx that were randomly sampled for training purposes.

Now you want to recover the spectral signatures for the training algorithm.

Hr = reshape(HSI,145*145,200) ; to get a 2D array out of the HSI.

class = cell(16,1) ; will contain the training samples for each class.

for k = 1 : 16

class{k} = Hr(Idx{k}(Sample(:),1),:) ;

end

Now class{1} contains no_samples spectral signatures. I guess that on indian pines 10 samples is plenty. Keep in mind that some clusters are very small (in no of pixels) on this dataset. Good Luck !

Comment: thanks a lot. Have you ever tried to do this problem up to now? I written some code for using this tool, but some times I faced this issue that Predicted Label just like the training label?!!!! and accuracy is around 50 %. however I've used only one time svmtrain and svmpred and set option to '-s 0', means C-SVM (multiclass). Is this wrong? please help me more about use LibSVM for classification Hyperspectral dataset like Indain pines. thanks regard

Comment: I haven't worked with SVM even though I know the theory, there are a lot of ways to solve the classification problem. What is your final goal ? Indian pines is quite hard to classify unfortunately. You might get better accuracy if you lower the number of clusters to 13. Also you could cut the image in half, use the first half for training and the second for testing. Or you can remove the sampled pixels from the image before training. Unfortunately it is hard to help without seeing more of your code, I'm sure there's documentation online.